# Black screen on log in

Tags: pantheon-files, greeter, desktop

I installed Unity desktop on ElementaryOS but after it caused slowness I decided to remove it. I saw this post on Askubuntu.com:

`sudo apt-get remove unity`

`sudo apt-get remove lightdm`

`sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop`

Unfortunately,  after these commands I reboot and my log in screen disappeared with a black screen. How can I resolve that? And what caused this to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I recall correctly, you should be able to press `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F2` and login with your username/password, then run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure pantheon-greeter` to do this.

Comment: You're very welcome. Glad it's fixed!